# MKAnnotation title width issue in iOS7

Tags: ios7, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have a problem with the width of labels inside Annotation in iOS7. The width of title and subtitle labels seems to be wider than necessary in iOS7 and the text gets cut by the annotation bubble on the right side.

```
    // Set some coordinates for our position
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = (double) 51.501468;
location.longitude = (double) -0.141596;

// Add the annotation to our map view
MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"POI djhkdjsahkljdhsakljhdlka01234" andCoordinate:location];

[self.mapa addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
```